# best way to export bigquery table with nested columns into csv file

Tags: google-bigquery

Friends,

I am trying to export BigQuery table with nested columns (Array, Struct) into CSV file by flattening the rows.

I have tried `bq export` and Python BQ API (`from google.cloud import bigquery`), both options.

Which approach would be better with respect to network performance and job scheduling ?

I was thinking of scheduling a job either on Scheduler or on Composer, which will run the export script to write csv file on cloud storage.

I know that `bq export` requires cloud sdk, whereas Python BQ API is suitable with Cloud Function. But trying to understand which approach is best w.r.t to performance. Is there any recommendation ?

Also any link related to them would be helpful.

Regards,
Sant

Comment: Could you describe your use case a bit more and about the job scheduling that you have mentioned?

Comment: @SandeepMohanty - edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no major difference in performance between the two.  `bq export` and Python BQ API are both written in Python, and they are both calling the same [BigQuery REST APIs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest) behind the scenes.

The main difference is whether you are writing a command line script vs writing a Python script.  Composer has both python_operator and bash_operator to work with either script.  So this is just a matter of programming language choice/preference.